# Production MobileFirst 7 Server upgrade from Worklight 6.2, Adapter call not working

Tags: upgrade, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

We have a MobileFirst application that worked with Worklight 6.2 server - production also. We are using a http adapter: `<connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">`

Currently we are changing the production server to 7.0.0. On Development Server we could test our application and all the functionalities were OK. We'we created the .war with the production server on build configuration and uploaded together with the android .wlapp . Now we receive 404 when the application tries to call any adapter function on production server. invokeProcedure onFailure returns UNEXPECTED_ERROR. This is with:

- Server version: 7.0.0.00.20150312-0731
- Project WAR version: 7.0.0.00.20150402-2001
- Adapter name: XXXXX. Version: 7.0.0.00.20150402-2001
- Application: XXXXX-android-0.9.7, Version: 7.0.0.00.20150402-2001

We have no security enabled in the application.
Is there something that must be enabled on Server in order to allow old type adapters call?
When we've tested with upgraded MobileFirst Development Studio 7.0.0.00.20150430 as development platform - same server version, and we got same 404 (Context not found), but there tries to connect with authorization/v1/clients/instance instead of /apps/services/api/XXXXX/android/query

Should a Server upgrade solve this problem? We've noticed that there are updates available.

The Server is on a https connection, but was same on WL 6.2.

Comment: Use the same server version and studio version. Supply messages.log, supply fuller error message.

Comment: Hello there, we've updated the server to the same version as studio. We could succesfully test the Android application as long it is not signed. But with the signed application and when adding publicSigningKey to the android configuration into application-descriptor.xml, the application connection to server fails. Here is the Android log: [link]http://m.uploadedit.com/ba3c/1431097202119.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the description in the comments and the supplied messages.log, it is clear that you are attempting to use Application Authenticity Protection.

This feature worked in a certain way in v6.2 and it works in a different way in v6.3 and above.
From the comments it appears you are only adding the `publickSigningKey` - this is no longer enough.

See the updated Application Authenticity Protection tutorial for steps to follow: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/authentication-security/application-authenticity-protection/

General steps to follow:

1. Setup authenticationConfig.xml with the security test
2. Add the security test to the environment node in application-descriptor.xml
3. Add the publicSigningKey to the `<publicSigningKey>` element
4. Add the application package name `<packageName>` element

I believe you are missing step 4.
Note that you also able to now enable the Extended Authenticity mode; follow the instructions in the tutorial.

Note about step 3: obviously the same keystore used to generate the publicSigningKey must be used when you export the signed .apk file... otherwise there will be a mismatch and the authenticity challenge will fail.

---

In your authenticationConfig.xml, make sure you have the securityTest available (= *not* commented out like in the file you've supplied in the comments below.

In your application-descriptor.xml, you are missing the securityTest attribute in the Android environment element: `<android version="0.9.9">` change to `<android version="0.9.9" securityTest="customTests">`

Comment: Hallo Idan, thank you for your quick answer. My configuration file looks like this [link]http://m.uploadedit.com/ba3c/1431099240756.txt

Comment: See my note at the bottom of my answer about the signing key you're using and the verification you must do.

Comment: Is it correctly configured my authenticationConfig.xml attached above? I have generate the <publicSigningKey> using "Extract public signing key" feature from eclipse when I click on android enviroment. Then I use same key file for Android Tools -> Export signed application package.

Comment: It is not. The customTests security test should NOT be commented out. In authenticationConfig.xml. Additionally it is missing from the android environment in application-descriptor.xml: securityTest="customTests"

Comment: Thank you for the support. After adding in authenticationconfig.xml the following configuration(from documentation) I could build signed app and distribute:
<customSecurityTest name="customTests">
         <test realm="wl_authenticityRealm" step="1"/>
     <test realm="wl_anonymousUserRealm" isInternalUserID="true" step="1"/>
     <test realm="wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm" step="2" isInternalDeviceID="true"/>
        </customSecurityTest>

Comment: @OlimpiuOlar, Your sentence is cut.

Comment: Sorry it was a writting error,  "-" should not be there. I connot correct it anymore.

Comment: Okay. So if this question is resolved, please mark as answered. Thanks. If no, explain what is not working.